# Reading in data line by line, but not all at once

Tags: c++

I am working on a project for my class. And I have gotten the entire thing to work, except one part. I am reading integers in from a file and turning them into a bankQueue, and eventList. I have to do this one line at a time.

My file looks like this.

```
1 5
2 5
4 5
20 5
22 5
24 5
26 5
28 5
30 5
88 3


// Get the first arrival event from the input file, and place it in eventList
tempArrivalEvent.type = ARRIVAL;
inFile >> tempArrivalEvent.beginTime >> tempArrivalEvent.transactionLength;
eventList.insert(tempArrivalEvent);
```

That is my first code which works to store the first line of data into the 2 variables. The problem I have is when I go to add the next line later on. The following code is in a different function than the code above.

```
if (!inFile.eof())
{
    tempArrivalEvent.type = ARRIVAL;
    inFile >> tempArrivalEvent.beginTime >> tempArrivalEvent.transactionLength;
anEventList.insert(tempArrivalEvent);
} // end if
```

The second code ends up taking the same exact line of data in as the first one. I need it to jump down to the next line but I can't figure it out. This is the only thing stopping my project from working.

Comment: A general helpfull tip: You shouldn't be using `if (!eof)`, instead use e.g. `if (inFile >> value1 >> value2)`. The `eof` flag will not be set until _after_ an input operation noticed that it reached the end of the file.

Comment: First, heed Joachim's advice on using `.eof()`. It is all-but-guaranteed *not* to be what you think it is. Second, you say: "The following code is in a different function than the code above". Is `inFile` being passed into the "different function" by-referenece, or is an entirely different `inFile` being used?

Comment: oh duh! since it's a totally different inFile, it doesnt even take into account the fact that I already took in the first line. I need to pass by reference the inFile.

Comment: @user2234688 See the answer posted below concerning proper validation and elimination of your improper `inFile.eof()` conundrum (which you probably don't even know you have yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, you're completely ignoring the potential failure of the actual **read** extractions of your two formatted inputs. It is beyond-easy to validate simply by examining the state of the istream as a result of the extraction. your first case then becomes:

```
tempArrivalEvent.type = ARRIVAL;
if (inFile >> tempArrivalEvent.beginTime >> tempArrivalEvent.transactionLength)
    eventList.insert(tempArrivalEvent);
```

Secondly, and likely more related to your code as-presented, consider this. `inFile.eof()` will not present `true` until you've attempted to read *beyond* EOF once you've arrived there (assuming all things have been successful until then). Therefore this code is not correct either:

```
if (!inFile.eof())  // nope, not set yet
{
    tempArrivalEvent.type = ARRIVAL;

    // both of these fail since we're at EOF, which will now be reported
    //  as such after the first failure. We, however, never check the stream
    //  status, and thus blindly insert whatever junk happened to be in the
    //  tempArrivalEvent object, likely data from a prior insert.
    inFile >> tempArrivalEvent.beginTime >> tempArrivalEvent.transactionLength;

    // insert unvalidated data
    anEventList.insert(tempArrivalEvent);
} // end if
```

This should be... *exactly the same as the initial read*. Validate the extraction success and only-then perform the event list insertion.

```
tempArrivalEvent.type = ARRIVAL;
if (inFile >> tempArrivalEvent.beginTime >> tempArrivalEvent.transactionLength)
    anEventList.insert(tempArrivalEvent);
```

Note: **All of this assumes `inFile` is the *same* `ifstream` object in both extraction code slices.** You've not clarified whether you're passing the first-case `inFile` by-reference to the second case in a different function. You need to pass it by-reference (or , shudder, use a global) if you want consecutive reads to work correctly.

Comment: alright gotcha, that makes sense now. I don't know what I was thinking before.